# Do "Shipping Tracking Code", "Consignment Number", "Shipping Code", "Shipping Number" share the same meaning?

Tags: vocabulary

do "Shipping Tracking Code", "Consignment Number", "Shipping Code", "Shipping Number" share the same meaning?

I want to use a very short term to express "Shipping Tracking Code" (is kind of unique code that locates the shipping item"

Can i use "Shipping Number" or "Shipping Code"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that any term that does not include the word 'tracking' is not clear enough. In my experience, a package can have both a shipping or consignment number *and* a tracking number. I would suggest 'tracking number' as the clearest option, if that's a number you're going to be giving to a customer.

Comment: but "Tracking number" can be anything like web tracking number, Item tracking number. But I want Shipping Tracking Number

Comment: Well, won't it be obvious it's a shipping tracking number given that it will be applied to an item being shipped?

Comment: is this term ok "SSCC" (The serial shipping container code), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_shipping_container_code

Comment: Who will be using the number? Give some context.

Comment: I am developing an Ordering system. Both buer & seller share the same info, if i just use the term "tracking code" then the seller  can understand, but the buyer may be confused

Comment: Will there be any other numbers attached to the shipment?

Comment: i don't know as people use my website so they need to understand the term on my website

Comment: i think shipping tracking code: is the only option here. This will make my webpage wastes extra 1 row